# Why does it not simulate keyboard event provided isTrusted true?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to simulate keyboard event from script. Basically I was just tinkering to make `isTrusted` to `true` by proxifying the events.

```js
const s = Symbol('listeners');

Node.prototype[s] = {}; // Initialize the symbol property

Node.prototype.addEventListener = new Proxy(Node.prototype.addEventListener, {
  apply(target, thisArg, args) {
    thisArg[s] = thisArg[s] || {}; // Access the symbol property

    if (args[0] in thisArg[s]) {
      thisArg[s][args[0]].push(args[1]);
    } else {
      thisArg[s][args[0]] = [args[1]];
    }

    return Reflect.apply(...arguments);
  }
});

Node.prototype.dispatchEvent = new Proxy(Node.prototype.dispatchEvent, {
  apply(target, thisArg, args) {
    const listeners = thisArg[s][args[0].type];
    if (listeners) {
      for (const listener of listeners) {
        const event = eventToObject(args[0]);
        event.isTrusted = true; // Set isTrusted to true
        listener(event);
      }
    }
  }
});

function eventToObject(event) {
  const object = {};
  for (const property in event) object[property] = event[property];
  return object;
}

const targetNode = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');

targetNode.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    console.log(event.isTrusted);
    console.log('Keydown event:', event.key);
});

const inputValue = 'hello';

for (let i = 0; i < inputValue.length; i++) {
  const char = inputValue.charAt(i);
  const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    key: char,
    code: `Key${char.toUpperCase()}`,
    bubbles: true
  });
  targetNode.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

It gives me the output `isTrusted true`. But it is not really filling the input target.

I know `isTrusted` is readable and won't be true in case you are dispatching the events from script. But how come is this possible here?

Comment: Because you're not really setting the value of the actual `Event`? You're setting the `isTrusted` property of a different object returned from `eventToObject`.